# row lock in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, locking

I have to do some network IO based on every row in a table with more than 70 million rows. Since high TPS is needed i have created a php script that does this task for a single row in table. I plan to call this php script using a cron job about 40 times every second. How do I do this so that no two script access the same row.

Comment: not by locking but by using exclusive ranges...without more specific info I doubt you'll get a more specific answer...

Answer (score 3):

To do it purely based on the table, you will need to set *something* In the table - a boolean, timestamp, deleting the row, etc - that indicates that you've processed the row. After that, a transaction is all you need.

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE processing = 0 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE table SET processing = 1 WHERE id = $id_of_what_we_got;
COMMIT;
-- process row here
-- optionally, tell the db we're done
UPDATE table SET processing = 2 WHERE id = $id_of_what_we_got;
```

Just make sure to use the same MySQL connection (PHP resource) for the entire transaction.

Further reading:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html
- https://github.com/ryandotsmith/Queue-Classic/blob/master/lib/queue_classic/durable_array.rb